# Struts 2 Select tag error

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl

I am new to Struts2. I want to compare JSTL's `c` tag and Struts2 `s` tag which one is easy to use... My code as below

ListDepartmentNameAction.java

```
package actions;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Array;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import service.ListDepNameService;

public class ListDepartmentNameAction extends ActionSupport{

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ListDepartmentNameAction.class);
ListDepNameService listDepNameService;
private List<String> allDNlist ;

public String execute() {

    allDNlist = listDepNameService.ListAllDepName();
    for (String ss : allDNlist) {
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
    log.info(allDNlist);
    return "success";

}

public ListDepNameService getListDepNameService() {
    return listDepNameService;
}

public void setListDepNameService(ListDepNameService listDepNameService) {
    this.listDepNameService = listDepNameService;
}

public List<String> getAllDNlist() {
    return allDNlist;
}

public void setAllDNlist(List<String> allDNlist) {
    this.allDNlist = allDNlist;
}   
}
```

query.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"      pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <head>
    <s:head />
      <h1 align="center" id="h1"></h1>
<body>

   <s:form action="listDepName" id="form" method="post">                
        <input name="Button" type="submit" id="listsubmit" value="List all Department Name" 
        onclick="javascirpt:abc(this)"/>                       
   </s:form>

   <select>
        <c:forEach items="${allDNlist}" var="item">
            <option value="abc" >${item}</option>
        </c:forEach>
   </select>

  <s:if test="%{allDNlist==null}">456</s:if>
  <s:else><s:select name="xxx" list="allDNlist" /></s:else> <!-- 1st -->

  <s:select name="xyz" list="allDNlist" /> <!-- 2nd -->

</body>
</html>
```

"allDNlist" can get value from action class,therefore, JSTL c tag work properly.
I don't understand why the "1st" struts2 select tag work fine, but "2nd" select `s` tag doesn't work, and got message like this

```
 HTTP Status 500 - tag 'select', field 'list', name 'xyz': The requested list key 'allDNlist' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

even I comment() the "2nd" select s tag, I still got same error message as above, only remove it.

Comment: Are you getting the values for the 1st select tag printed?

Comment: Yes, the 1st select tag work no problem and can get correct result in select drop-down box.

Comment: What happens if you put the second select in the else block?

Comment: Just like second select, no error.

Comment: Only the submit button is actually in a form.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I reproduced your whole code and it is perfectly working.

Note that you don't close `</head>` tag, i reproduced that too and it works the same...
It should be

```
<head>
   <s:head/>
</head>
```

You should declare your `ListDepNameService listDepNameService;` as private too (you already have the accessors), and check what type of List is returned.

I tested the code with

```
    allDNlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    allDNlist.add("Valore 1 ");
    allDNlist.add("Valore 2 ");
    allDNlist.add("Valore 3 ");
```

in execute() method, this is the only difference.

Please try this instead the service call, and let me know...

Comment: Hi Andrea,thanks for reply. The 1st select tag work fine without creating attribute in action class.And I give it a try to creating "private int xyz" for 2nd select tag in action class and generating its getter and setter, but still got same error message result...

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar type of collection error while populating the drop down with `<s:select:`  tag. after research i figured out that "i did not initialize my instance variable List" in your case make `private List<String> allDNlist = new ArrayList<String>();` should solve the problem.

Comment: I am not sure  I understand the answer. Try to improve your answer please.